# How do I extract a particular value from a string with a condition using regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex, numpy

my input string
`This is Bruno. He is a service shark. Only gets out of the 12.5/11 water to assist you. 13.5/10 terrifyingly good boy`

In the string above, I want to extract `13.5` instead of `12.5` so I did this:
Here is the code

```
    a = re.search(r"\d*\.\d+|\d+\/\'10'", text)
    print(a.group())
```

```
# 12.5
```

How should I do it?

Comment: `r'\d*\.\d+(?!.*\d\.\d)'` or `r'\d*\.\d+(?!.*\.\d)'` to extract the last occurrence of a float number (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/HwdRU7/1)).

Comment: your desired output?